# how to replace '\\\' to '\'?

Tags: php, regex

my code is not working ? and i dont want to use str_replace , for there maybe more slashes than 3 to be replaced. how can i do the job using preg_replace?
my code here like this:

```
<?php

$str='<li>
                <span class=\"highlight\">Color</span>
                Can\\\'t find the exact color shown on the model pictures? Just leave a message (eg: color as shown in the first picture...) when you place order.
                Please note that colors on your computer monitor may differ slightly from actual product colors depending on your monitor settings.
            </li>';
$str=preg_replace("@\\+@","\\",$str);
echo $str;
```

[image]

Comment: Well, you said you have that messy `Can\\\'t` in database. Why do you have such a weird thing in database? What if you originally put correct data, not rubbish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is merit in the other answers, but to me it looks like what you're actually trying to accomplish is something very different. In the php code `\\\'` is not three slashes followed by an apostrophe, it's one escaped slash followed by an escaped apostrophe, and in the rendered output, that's exactly what you see—a slash followed by an apostrophe (with no need to escape them in the rendered html). It's important to realize that the escape character is not *actually*  part of the string; it's merely a way to help you represent a character that normally has very different meaning in within php—in this case, an apostrophe normally terminates a string literal. What looks like 4 characters in php is actually only 2 characters in the string.

If this is the extent of your code, there's no need for string manipulation or regular expressions. What you actually need is just this:

```
<?php
$str='<li>
                <span class="highlight">Color</span>
                Can\'t find the exact color shown on the model pictures? Just leave a message (eg: color as shown in the first picture...) when you place order.
                Please note that colors on your computer monitor may differ slightly from actual product colors depending on your monitor settings.
            </li>';
echo $str;
?>
```

Only one escape character is needed here for the apostrophe, and in the rendered HTML you will see no slashes at all.

**Further Reading:**

- [Escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Comment: but my code in database is like this now '\\\',i must replace to one \ before I echo them to html

Comment: @mingfish_004: if in database you see it as `\\\ ` - then in string literal in php it should be `\\\\\\ `

Comment: Run a MySQL replace function to permanently fix this in the database, and make sure it's not happening anymore when inputting into the database.

Comment: @Anton agreed, and it's much better to ensure that your data is clean before it gets to the database rather than trying to pretty it up after the fact.

Answer (score 4):

The root of this problem is actually in how it was written into your database and likely to be caused by [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php); this was used in older versions and a really [bad idea](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php).

**The best fix**

This requires a few steps:

1. Fix the script that puts the HTML inside your database by disabling [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).
2. Write a script that reads all existing database entries, applies [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/stripslashes) and saves the changes.
3. Fix the presentation part (though, that may need no changes at all.

**Alternative patch**

Use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/stripslashes) before you present the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern

```
preg_replace('@\\+@', '\\', $text);
```

Comment: How is this different from the OP's version?

Comment: In regex PHP, you should use **4** backslashes to represent **1** backslash.

Answer (score 0):

This replaces two or more \ symbols preceding an ' symbol with \'

```
$theConvertedString = preg_replace("/\\{2,}'/", "\'", $theSourceString);
```

Ideally, you shouldn't have code causing this issue in the first place so I would have a look at why you have \\' in your code to begin with. If you've manually put it in your variables, take it out. Often, this also happens with multiple calls to addslashes() or mysql_real_escape_string() or a cheap hosting providers' automatic transformation of all POST request variables to escape slashes, combined with your server side PHP code to do the same.

Comment: In regex PHP, you should use **4** backslashes to represent **1** backslash.

Comment: @HamZa That's for when you use single quotes to enclose the expression string. In this case, I used double quotes to make it easier to read, so I only need 2.